# Why can a linear "ordinary" differential equation have non-linear coefficients of independent variable?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry

The confusion origins from the fact that $y$ = $x^2$ + $x$ + $1$ is a non linear equation but $y\,'$ = $x^2$ + $x$ + $1$ is a linear differential equation.

1. Why is the non-linearity in independent variable not significant in the case of differential equations?
2. Does the word linear have different meanings for "normal" (not differential) equations and differential equations?
3. What would be the best way to make some geometric sense of linear differential equations? (like in the case of linear equation in two variable it is a line.)

*Mentions of "differential equation(s)" in the above questions refer to only the subset of "ordinary differential equation(s)"*

Comment: I got an impression from somewhere that linear functions or linear maps, as in linear algebra are the functions which follow $f(a\vec{v_1} + b \vec{v_2}) = a f (\vec{v_1}) + b f( \vec{v_2})$ and a linear equation (of an independent variable $x$) as in calculus is an equation in which the highest power of $x$ is one. But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: A linear equation of a variable $x$ is a polynomial equation of degree one exactly because those are the functions that are linear maps in the sense of linear algebra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "linear" here means that if $u$ and $v$ are solutions of the (homogeneous) ODE, so is $\alpha u + \beta v$. That the coefficients of the derivatives aren't linear doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

You're confused about what the independent variable is. A differential equation is a statement about *functions*, not about *numbers*.

In this case, the equation $y' = x^2 + x + 1$ is a statement about two functions:

- $y$
- $(x^2 + x + 1)$.

Neither of them need be linear in $x$. However it *is* linear in $y$. To see why (hah) first let's call $g(x) = (x^2 + x + 1)$ so we don't get distracted by $x$'s:
$$ y' = g $$
This is linear in the same way that the equation $3x = 7$ is a linear equation: on the left side we have a linear function, and on the right side we have a constant.

Let's look at a more complicated example just to be sure we understand. 
$$3xy' - 2y' + 7y/x + 3x = -x^2 + 2y$$
Rearrange so all the terms with "$y$" are on the left side and everything is on the right, and factor out so it looks like a polynomial in $y$.
$$ \big(3x - 2\big)y' + \bigg(-2 + \frac{7}{x}\bigg)y = -x^2 - 3x $$
This is a differential equation, so it's a statement about *functions*, not *numbers*. Let's call $a(x) = 3x-2$, $b(x) = -2 + 7/x$, and $c(x) = -x^2 - 3x$ just so the $x$'s don't get in the way:
$$ay' + by = c$$
Again on the left side we have a linear function of $y$, and on the right side we have a constant.

---

Why is the left side a linear function of $y$? Let's call $Ly = ay' + by$. You should work this out: $$L(y_1 + y_2) = Ly_1 + Ly_2$$ and $$L(\lambda y) = \lambda Ly.$$
This problem lives in the realm of linear algebra: $L$ is a linear operator, and we're solving the inhomogeneous equation
$$ Ly = c $$

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite your two equations to
$$
f(x,y) = x^2+x+1-y = 0
$$
and
$$
F(y)= x^2+x+1-y'=0.
$$
It is instructive to identify which kind of maps we are dealing with: $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function of two real variables, whereas $F:C^1(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C(\mathbb{R})$ is a function that takes as argument a continuously differentiable function. I.e. by interpreting $y$ as a function of $x$ (and thus as element $y \in C^1(\mathbb{R}))$, $F$ only takes one argument.

We can further write $F(y)=F_0(y)+c$, where $c=x^2+x+1$ is viewed as an element in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $F_0(y)=-y'$. Then $F_0$ is a linear map between the vector-spaces $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $C(\mathbb{R})$, which means that $F$ is an affine linear map.

On the other hand, $f$ is non-linear. This is the reason to call the first equation non-linear and the second equation (affine) linear.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to understand the definition. First, a differential equation is an equation in the differential of an unknown function, and the function itself. Thus it is linear provided it involves only a linear combination of the differential of the unknown, and the unknown, the coefficient being given functions of the independent variables. That's all.

Thus, $f(x)\mathrm dy+yg(x)\mathrm dx=0$ is linear for any given functions $f,g$ whereas $y\mathrm dy+\mathrm dx=0$ is nonlinear because the coefficient of $\mathrm dy,$ an unknown, is itself the unknown $y.$

In general, it is just an equation of the form $$\sum_{k\ge 0} f_k(x,\mathrm dx)\mathrm d^ky=F(x,\mathrm dx),$$ where the functions $f_k, \,F$ are given, and the equation is homogeneous in the differentials.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First consider an example from the theory of linear equations in algebra.  Let $M$ be a given matrix and let $v$ be an unknown vector.  Then we can talk about solutions to the equation
$$
Mv=0,
$$
where $0$ is the zero vector.  This equation represents a system of linear equations and, as one might expect, we say that the matrix equation is linear.  It has the important property that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two solutions to the equation, then $av_1+bv_ 2$ is also a solution, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary scalars.  We refer to this property as *linearity*.

Consider now the equation $Mv=c$, where $c$ is a given vector.  If $c$ is not the zero vector then we do not have the property of linearity anymore since if $Mv_1=c$ and $Mv_2=c$ we have $M(av_1+bv_2)=ac+bc$, which is not equal to $c$ for arbitrary $a$ and $b$.  What we do have is that if $u$ is a solution to $Mu=c$ and $v_1$ and $v_2$ are solutions to $Mv=0$ then $u+av_1+bv_2$ is a solution to $Mu=c$.

What is important in all this is that $M$ is a linear operator: it satisfies
$$M(av_1+bv_2)=aMv_1+bMv_2.
$$
From this, everything said above follows: linear combinations of solutions to the *homogeneous* equation $Mv=0$ are also solutions of the homogeneous equation; a solution to the *inhomogeneous* equation $Mu=c$ plus an arbitrary linear combination of solutions to the homogeneous equation is also a solution to the inhomogeneous equation $Mv=c$.

The same terminology applies to linear differential equations.  The analog of the matrix $M$ is the linear differential operator, of which
$$
L=x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+(2x^2+1)\frac{d}{dx}+(x^3+x+1)
$$
is an example.  If $f$ is a function, then $L$ acts on $f$ as follows:
$$
Lf(x)=xf''(x)+(2x^2+1)f'(x)+(x^3+x+1)f(x).
$$

Now suppose $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are solutions to the homogenous equation $Lf(x)=0$.  You can easily check using basic properties of $\frac{d}{dx}$ that $af_1(x)+bf_2(x)$ is also a solution, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary numbers.  The geometric meaning of this property is *superposition*: solutions can simply be added together or rescaled and they remain solutions.

If $g(x)$ is a solution to the inhomogeneous equation $Lg(x)=P(x)$, where $P$ is some non-zero function, then $g(x)+af_1(x)+bf_2(x)$ also solves the inhomogeneous equation.

Let key property of $L$ here is again that of being a linear operator: $$
L(af_1(x)+bf_2(x))=aLf_1(x)+bLf_2(x).
$$
The ability to combine solutions allows a nice theory of linear differential equations to be constructed.  Non-linear differential equations (an example of which would be $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+[f(x)]^2=0$) do not have this combining property, which makes the theory considerably more difficult.

The example in your question, $y'=x^2+x+1$, is an inhomogeneous equation.  The solutions to the homogenous equation $y'=0$ are the constant functions.  The fact that an arbitrary integration constant can be added to any particular solution to your equation to find another solution is linearity at work.